# How to write Junit5 test cases in Springboot for apache camel Producer Template sendBodyAndHeader() to publish a json event to kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, junit5, spring-restcontroller

Need a help to write junit5 test case in springboot for a post api where it uses apache camel producer template to send message to kafka. Please find the controller class details for which junit test cases are required. Note-I don't have any service/repository layer for this.This is standalone controller which is responsible to publish message to kafka by using camel producer template.Thanks is advance.

**Controller Class-->**

```
`
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.rms.inventory.savr.audit.model.AuditInfo;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class MockKafkaProducerController {
  @Autowired ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
  @Value("${audit.inbound.endpoint.kafka.uri:audit-json-topic}")
  private String auditTopicKafka;
  @Value("${camel.component.kafka.consumer.supply}")
  private String supplyLineUpdateKafkaTopic;
  @Value("${camel.component.kafka.consumer.demand}")
  private String demandLineUpdateKafkaTopic;
  @Value("${camel.component.kafka.consumer.supply-bucket}")
  private String supplybucketTopicKafka;
  @Value("${camel.component.kafka.consumer.demand-bucket}")
  private String demandbucketTopicKafka;
  @Value("${camel.component.kafka.consumer.availability}")
  private String availabilityTopicKafka;
  private Map<String, String> dataTypeTopicMap;
  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
    dataTypeTopicMap =
        Map.of(
            "SUPPLY_LINE",
            supplyLineUpdateKafkaTopic,
            "SUPPLY_BUCKET",
            supplybucketTopicKafka,
            "DEMAND_LINE",
            demandLineUpdateKafkaTopic,
            "DEMAND_BUCKET",
            demandbucketTopicKafka,
            "AVAILABILITY",
            availabilityTopicKafka);
  }
  @PostMapping("/api/mock/producer")
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveAuditInfo(@RequestBody AuditInfo auditInfo)
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveAuditInfo(
      @RequestBody AuditInfo auditInfo, @RequestHeader("AUDIT_TYPE") String auditType)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    if (auditType == null || auditType.isEmpty()) {
      auditType = "SUPPLY_LINE";
    }
    String topicName = dataTypeTopicMap.get(auditType);
    //  producerTemplate.
    producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(
        auditTopicKafka, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(auditInfo), "messageFormat", "CANONICAL");
        topicName, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(auditInfo), "messageFormat", "CANONICAL");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Boolean.TRUE);
  }
  @PostMapping("/api/inventory/audit/mock/producer")
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> publishInventoryAudit(@RequestBody String auditInfo)
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> publishInventoryAudit(
      @RequestBody String auditInfo, @RequestHeader("AUDIT_TYPE") String auditType)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
    producerTemplate.sendBody(auditTopicKafka, auditInfo);
    if (auditType == null || auditType.isEmpty()) {
      auditType = "SUPPLY_LINE";
    }
    String topicName = dataTypeTopicMap.get(auditType);
    producerTemplate.sendBody(topicName, auditInfo);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Boolean.TRUE);
  }
}`
```

`

I tried to mock producer template but not able to fix.

Comment: Have you tried to write any test yet on your own that starts your webserver?

Comment: I am new to springboot,I am able to do write the rest of test cases for the flow like camel routing,repository layer etc.Need help in this topic.As unable to find any leads also from internet.

Comment: So ["test restcontroller with junit5"](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/rest-controller-unit-test-example/) resulting in nothing useful?

Comment: It's not a regular  MV Ccontroller where you have service and repo,as mentioned in my question its an independent api which is uses camel producer template to publish messages into kafka events.I am not finding exact test case for this, yes event publishing even could be possible through kafka template but as i m using camel is next layer to do transformation and process so would like to reuse the producer template instead of kafka template.

Comment: You still have a rest controller. Camel shouldn't matter. Otherwise, you should refactor your code with dependency injection to make it easier to test in isolation

Comment: do you have any reference code for rest controller with kafka producer template, if yes please share.

Comment: *camel producer template not kafka producer template

Comment: I do not because I don't use Kafka producers in RESTControllers, Camel or otherwise... Besides, no part of your question seems to be [using Camel Kafka producer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/kafka-component.html#_producing_messages_to_kafka), and as I said, you can [test camel in isolation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/others/test-spring-junit5.html)

Comment: test camel alone already i have taken care i was looking only for this part lv it,,thank you